# How to add constrainlayout only to floating actio button?

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to add constrainlayout only two the last two floating action button with nested framelayout. any help would be highly appreciated. My main idea is to able to move and position the floating action button from graphical user interface.

I have notice that android gravity help to put button at right and the center from right with

> ```
>         android:layout_gravity="right|center"
> ```

how can i add a button at right but between center and end at bottom.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MediaPresentationActivity"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <VideoView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/videoViewPresentation"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewPresentation"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:src="@drawable/serv24logobig" />

            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
//*how to add only below two floating action button as constrainlayout //

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"

        android:visibility="visible"

        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"
        android:visibility="visible"

        app:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorMultiSelectHighlight"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Tashi, as written, it's very difficult to understand what is that you're trying to achieve, what you have done, and what is not working. You're going to need to supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you want, so we can help you. There's no reason why you can't just simply wrap the fabs in a a Constraint Layout, but why, and what for, is not clear.

Comment: how can i add constrain layout only two the last two floating action button

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayouts only allow ONE child (well they allow N children, but they overlap, because it doesn't support children positioning, rather it expects them to take all the available space), so if you want to use a ConstraintLayout to position two items inside a FrameLayout, then you need to ensure that the children of your FrameLayout, is a ViewGroup that allows positioning of its own children.

Let's see what you got.

Your Root is a FrameLayout, perhaps you should consider making it a ConstraintLayout to begin with...

You're asking your Root layout to wrap its contents. Unless this is a custom view, this is somewhat frowning, but not wrong; since I don't know how you're using this, it's hard  to tell if this is the correct approach in this case.

I don't know how your UI should look, but from what I see, you have a series of nested LinearLayouts, Vertical, then Horizontal to have an ImageView and a VideoView... not sure how you expect these to be positioned.

Down Below you have an empty LinearLayout... (?)

and then you tossed the two FABs.

This is not going to work. I suggest you revisit your entire Layout (which, btw, is incorrect as pasted, because you're closing the `FrameLayout` twice...).

If you post an image of what your desired output is, perhaps we can help you better understand where your problem is. As it is, it's not possible to determine.

The answer to your question, as written at this time is:

"How can I add a constraint Layout onlo to the last two FABs?"

You can't (for the purposes I think you want), but if you really want to see why, and what would happen:

Simply add, **inside your FrameLayout** this:

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <!-- YOUR FABS GO HERE -->

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will obviously NOT LOOK THE WAY YOU WANT, but that's why I asked you in the comment above, "show us what you want, we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you need".

There was a reason why I asked that, not to annoy you, but to help you. You chose to ignore it, and that's as far as I can go to help you with the information I have.